# How can I stop this javascript code from deleting the origin/first row of my table?

Tags: javascript, html

Using the code, you can see that it's easy to create new rows, and then delete them. The problem I'm having is that the default/origin/first row (A-T) will also delete - I need to block this row from deleting. Can this be done?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>Q</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>T</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<script>

function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).contentEditable = true;
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1).contentEditable = true;
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2).contentEditable = false;
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3).contentEditable = false;
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4).contentEditable = true;
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5).contentEditable = false;
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6).contentEditable = true;
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7).contentEditable = false;
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8).contentEditable = false;
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9).contentEditable = false;
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(10).contentEditable = false;
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(11).contentEditable = false;
    var cell13 = row.insertCell(12).contentEditable = false;
    var cell14 = row.insertCell(13).contentEditable = false;
    var cell15 = row.insertCell(14).contentEditable = false;
    var cell16 = row.insertCell(15).contentEditable = false;
    var cell17 = row.insertCell(16).contentEditable = false;
    var cell18 = row.insertCell(17).contentEditable = false;
    var cell19 = row.insertCell(18).contentEditable = false;
    var cell20 = row.insertCell(19).contentEditable = false;
    cell1.innerHTML = "";
    cell2.innerHTML = "";
    cell3.innerHTML = "";
    cell4.innerHTML = "";
    cell5.innerHTML = "";
    cell6.innerHTML = "";
    cell7.innerHTML = "";
    cell8.innerHTML = "";
    cell9.innerHTML = "";
    cell10.innerHTML = "";
    cell11.innerHTML = "";
    cell12.innerHTML = "";
    cell13.innerHTML = "";
    cell14.innerHTML = "";
    cell15.innerHTML = "";
    cell16.innerHTML = "";
    cell17.innerHTML = "";
    cell18.innerHTML = "";
    cell19.innerHTML = "";
    cell20.innerHTML = "";

}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(-1);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but it's the time to learn [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) ... More related: `row.insertCell(0).contentEditable = true;` returns `true`, not the newly-created cell. It's not useful to add `innerHTML` to a boolean ..?

Answer (score 1):

Your current delete function blindly deletes the last row of the table.

```
function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

If the first row is all you want to preserve, then ensure that the table has more than 1 row(s) before deleting the last one.

```
function myDeleteFunction() {
    // There are at least 2 or more rows. So the last one can be deleted
    if(document.getElementById("myTable1").rows.length > 1){
        document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just verify there is more than 1 `tr` within the table before you delete it:

```
if (document.getElementById("myTable1").getElementsByTagName('tr').length > 1) {
    document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(-1);
}
```

Full code, for code-snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>Q</td>
    <td>R</td>
    <td>S</td>
    <td>T</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<script>

function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0).contentEditable = true;
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1).contentEditable = true;
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2).contentEditable = false;
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3).contentEditable = false;
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4).contentEditable = true;
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5).contentEditable = false;
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6).contentEditable = true;
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7).contentEditable = false;
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8).contentEditable = false;
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9).contentEditable = false;
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(10).contentEditable = false;
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(11).contentEditable = false;
    var cell13 = row.insertCell(12).contentEditable = false;
    var cell14 = row.insertCell(13).contentEditable = false;
    var cell15 = row.insertCell(14).contentEditable = false;
    var cell16 = row.insertCell(15).contentEditable = false;
    var cell17 = row.insertCell(16).contentEditable = false;
    var cell18 = row.insertCell(17).contentEditable = false;
    var cell19 = row.insertCell(18).contentEditable = false;
    var cell20 = row.insertCell(19).contentEditable = false;
    cell1.innerHTML = "";
    cell2.innerHTML = "";
    cell3.innerHTML = "";
    cell4.innerHTML = "";
    cell5.innerHTML = "";
    cell6.innerHTML = "";
    cell7.innerHTML = "";
    cell8.innerHTML = "";
    cell9.innerHTML = "";
    cell10.innerHTML = "";
    cell11.innerHTML = "";
    cell12.innerHTML = "";
    cell13.innerHTML = "";
    cell14.innerHTML = "";
    cell15.innerHTML = "";
    cell16.innerHTML = "";
    cell17.innerHTML = "";
    cell18.innerHTML = "";
    cell19.innerHTML = "";
    cell20.innerHTML = "";

}

function myDeleteFunction() {
     
    if (document.getElementById("myTable1").getElementsByTagName('tr').length > 1) {
        document.getElementById("myTable1").deleteRow(-1);
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HUGE thank you to everyone for your assistance. I realize I am a novice, so I appreciate even more you experts taking the time to assist me.